# EBS container-commands: wrong django-admin working directory?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a rather simple django application which I deploy on elastic beanstalk environment. I have created a number of customisations to the deployment process, including the classic "collectstatic" script in container commands. Here is part of my config:

```
container_commands:
    01_replace_wsgi_config:
        command: cp .ebextensions/wsgi.conf /opt/python/ondeck/wsgi.conf
    02_collect_static:
        command: django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput
```

As you can see, I use the ondeck folder to customise wsgi.conf file, since the one that is being automatically generated is not good enough for me.

Now the problem I have stumbled upon is that the django-admin.py invocation above is working on the old "current" directory, and its results are not visible once the "ondeck" directory becomes "current" - which happens, apparently, *after* the `container_commands` are executed. This looks as 404 for my javascript files that come from django installed applications. The way I found that out is by watching the /var/log/eb-actions.log output:

```
  ...
  Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jquery/static/js/jquery.js'
  Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_ajax/static/django_ajax/js/jquery.ajax.min.js'
  Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_ajax/static/django_ajax/js/jquery.ajax-plugin.js'
  Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_ajax/static/django_ajax/js/jquery.ajax.js'
  Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_ajax/static/django_ajax/js/jquery.ajax-plugin.min.js'

  0 static files copied to '/opt/python/current/app/dashboard/dashboard/static', 74 unmodified.
```

I have found a solution that works good for me:

```
02_collect_static:
    command: python dashboard/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

This command makes sure that collectstatic is run on the "ondeck" forder, which is about to become "current":

```
  ...
  Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jquery/static/js/jquery.js'
  Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_ajax/static/django_ajax/js/jquery.ajax.min.js'
  Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_ajax/static/django_ajax/js/jquery.ajax-plugin.js'
  Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_ajax/static/django_ajax/js/jquery.ajax.js'
  Copying '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_ajax/static/django_ajax/js/jquery.ajax-plugin.min.js'

  67 static files copied to '/opt/python/bundle/15/app/dashboard/dashboard/static', 7 unmodified.
```

What makes me worried, is that I had to change something that should had been working according to the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands).

I suspect that my problem may be hidden here (app.config):

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "dashboard.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/dashboard:$PYTHONPATH"
```

PYTHONPATH is set to "current", which may force the django-admin.py look there instead of the "ondeck" when processing container_commands. 
If so, how should this setting look like for a correct classic deployment to work? I took this format [from documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-deploy)...

Comment: how did you fix this finally?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this for a number of projects and it works great.

```
02_collectstatic:
  command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

option_settings looks good.